# Bits mask - bitwise operations in C

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, bit-manipulation, mask

Example: I have this binary representation of integer `0000010010001110`

How i can mask this bits by this `110..... 0.......` ?
i need to save zeros in mask and save all active bits
in following integer `110010001110`

i'm newbie in bitwise ops so give me some ideas or advice,please,thanks.

upd. i'm need to mask wchar_t and output that in unicode (UTF-8)
representation

> Read the UTF-8 specs for more detail, but at a high level:
>
> Code points 0 – 007F are stored as regular, single-byte ASCII. Code
>   points 0080 and above are converted to binary and stored (encoded) in
>   a series of bytes. The first “count” byte indicates the number of
>   bytes for the codepoint, including the count byte. These bytes start
>   with 11..0:
>
> 110xxxxx (The leading “11” is indicates 2 bytes in sequence, including
>   the “count” byte)
>
> 1110xxxx (1110 -> 3 bytes in sequence)
>
> 11110xxx (11110 -> 4 bytes in sequence)
>
> Bytes starting with 10… are “data” bytes and contain information for
>   the codepoint. A 2-byte example looks like this
>
> 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Showing more pairs of sample input and desired result might help. You should also show the effort you have made yourself. Making a [mcve] gives a good impression. Even if you have no idea how to go on, your MCVE should contain an input (e.g. an unsigned int variable) which contains whatever you want processed and an output, e.g. another variable which in the end should contain the result.

Comment: @Yunnosch i'm try,thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i'm need to mask wchar_t and output that in unicode (UTF-8) representation

Have you read the official specification of [UTF-8 in the Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404) (Section 3.9 - Unicode Encoded Forms), or [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), or even the [UTF-8 documentation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) yet?

They describe the algorithm needed to split a 21-bit codepoint number into an encoded byte sequence. Note that `wchar_t` is 16-bit ([UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)) on Windows but is 32-bit ([UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)) on most other platforms. Converting between UTFs is fairly straight forward, but you do have to take into account what the UTFs actually are, as converting UTF-16 to UTF-8 is a bit different than converting UTF-32 to UTF-8.

In a nutshell, you need something like this:

```
uint32_t codepoint = ...;
// This is the actual codepoint number, decoded from 1 or 2 wchar_t
// elements, depending on the UTF encoding of the wchar_t sequence.
// In UTF-32, the characters are the actual codepoint numbers as-is.
// In UTF-16, only the characters <= 0xFFFF are the actual codepoint
// numbers, the rest are encoded using surrogate pairs that you would
// have to decode to get the actual codepoint numbers...

uint8_t bytes[4];
int numBytes = 0;

if (codepoint <= 0x7F)
{
    bytes[0] = (uint8_t) codepoint;
    numBytes = 1;
}
else if (codepoint <= 0x7FF)
{
    bytes[0] = 0xC0 | (uint8_t) ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x1F);
    bytes[1] = 0x80 | (uint8_t) (codepoint & 0x3F);
    numBytes = 2;
}
else if (codepoint <= 0xFFFF)
{
    bytes[0] = 0xE0 | (uint8_t) ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x0F);
    bytes[1] = 0x80 | (uint8_t) ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F);
    bytes[2] = 0x80 | (uint8_t) (codepoint & 0x3F);
    numBytes = 3;
}
else if (codepoint <= 0x10FFFF)
{
    bytes[0] = 0xF0 | (uint8_t) ((codepoint >> 18) & 0x07);
    bytes[1] = 0x80 | (uint8_t) ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3F);
    bytes[2] = 0x80 | (uint8_t) ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F);
    bytes[3] = 0x80 | (uint8_t) (codepoint & 0x3F);
    numBytes = 4;
}
else
{
    // illegal!
}

// use bytes[] up to numBytes as needed...
```

Which can be simplified to something like this:

```
uint32_t codepoint = ...; // decoded from wchar_t sequence...

uint8_t bytes[4];
int numBytes = 0;

if (codepoint <= 0x7F)
{
    bytes[0] = 0x00;
    numBytes = 1;
}
else if (codepoint <= 0x7FF)
{
    bytes[0] = 0xC0;
    numBytes = 2;
}
else if (codepoint <= 0xFFFF)
{
    bytes[0] = 0xE0;
    numBytes = 3;
}
else if (codepoint <= 0x10FFFF)
{
    bytes[0] = 0xF0;
    numBytes = 4;
}
else
{
    // illegal!
}

for(int i = 1; i < numBytes; ++i)
{
    bytes[numBytes-i] = 0x80 | (uint8_t) (codepoint & 0x3F);
    codepoint >>= 6;
}

bytes[0] |= (uint8_t) codepoint;

// use bytes[] up to numBytes as needed...
```

In your example, `0000010010001110` is decimal 1166, hex 0x48E.  [Codepoint U+048E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/048e/index.htm) is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `0xD2 0x8E`, eg:

```
0000010010001110b -> 010010b 001110b
0xC0 or 010010b -> 0xD2
0x80 or 001110b -> 0x8E
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you need exactly,but in case you need to "recognize" the types of “count” byte and “data” byte,for the given example:

`1100000110100000`(11000001 10100000)

to "recognize" "count" byte you can use:

```
#define BIT_MASK 0X8000 //which gives---1000 0000 0000 0000
```

and then use operator `&` to check if bit is set,a `counter` to count how many bits are set,and a `<<` operator,to shift left(8 times maximum). In case a bit which is not set appeared,break.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdint.h>
  #define BIT_MASK        0x8000
  #define MAX_LEFT_SHIFT  8

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t exm_num = 49568;// for example 11000001 10100000 in binary
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_LEFT_SHIFT;++i){
    if (exm_num & BIT_MASK)
        ++count;
     else
         break;
     exm_num = exm_num<<1;
 }
     return 0;
}
```

You can then use the final value of `count` to identify the type.

Output for that given example would be 2